# Unknown abbreviations in תפארת ישראל commentary on the Mishnah

Tags: words, maseches-terumos

A סאה of תרומה that fell into 100 סאה of חולין becomes בטל. If two סאה of תרומה fall into 100 סאה of חולין it does not become בטל. If one סאה falls in and afterwards another סאה falls in. If the owner knew about the first one falling in before the second one falling in ר"ש says the first became בטל so therefore when the second one falls in it to becomes בטל. It is as if one סאה fell into 100 חולין each time which is מותר.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

This is the text of the mishna:
סְאָה תְרוּמָה שֶׁנָּפְלָה לְמֵאָה, וְלֹא הִסְפִּיק לְהַגְבִּיהָהּ עַד שֶׁנָּפְלָה אַחֶרֶת, הֲרֵי זוֹ אֲסוּרָה. וְרַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן מַתִּיר

I am having trouble reading the תפארת ישראל on the mishna: THE BOLD ARE THE WORDS I DO NOT KNOW WHAT THEY MEAN. Any help is greatly appreciated.
הרי זו אסורה ורבי שמעון מתיר
והיינו משום דאיסורו רק מדרבנן דמדאוריי' כבר נתבטל ברוב כיבש ביבש. ודוקא היכא דנודע בינתיים נפילה ראשונה. דר"ש לטעמיה דס"ל [ב"ק דע"ו] דכל העומד לתרום כתרום דמי. ואילה"ק לרבנן דקיי"ל כוותי'. הרי קיי"ל נמי דיבש ביבש שנתבטל אינו **חו"נ** [כי"ד צ"ט ש"ך סק"א].**ש"ך** י"ל תרומה שאני דלא הרים עדיין התרומה שצריך להרים:‏

Link to Mishna:
[תרומות פרק ה משנה ו](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Terumot.5.8?ven=Mishnah_Yomit_by_Dr._Joshua_Kulp&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=he&with=Yachin&lang2=he)

Comment: try "חוזר ונעור returns and awakens" (referring to the prohibition). Not sure which source he's referencing exactly, doesn't seem to be shach yd 99:1 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A6%D7%98_%D7%90 maybe there's a typo somewhere, whoever figures it out can post this

Comment: חו''נ = חוזר וניעור

Comment: From wikitext   קיי"ל נמי דיבש ביבש שנתבטל אינו חו"נ [כי"ד צ"ט ש"ך סק"א]. י"ל תרומה שאני דלא הרים עדיין התרומה שצריך להרים:

Comment: ש''ך is sifse Cohen a comment on SA

Comment: In משניות זכר חנוך it has the word ש"ך, Sefaria does not. Not sure what's goin on there.

Comment: Your quote has a typo because the word Shach is duplicated after the parenthesis